# Android: same activity, different onClick listeners

Tags: android, android-activity

at the moment i have 2 activities which have exactly the same view. However, when you click on an item, the actions performed are different. This is redundant and I would like to use only 1 activity with 2 different onClick behaviours.

Both activities can be reached by clicking on a button in the main menu. How do i distinguish which button was clicked and customise the onClick actions?

A.java:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_identify_animals);
    setupActionBar();

    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridviewidentify);            
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));     

    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });     
}
```

B.java:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_report_animal);
    setupActionBar();
    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridviewreport);          
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));           

    // Set up onClick listener
    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

            DialogConfirmation.LaunchNewDialog(B.this, "Title", "Message.", "Action", "Cancel");                
        }
    });         
}
```

Comment: please post you code on the listener so far ?

Comment: Put a flag, make two functions, call either(`from within your onClickListener`) based on the value of the flag.

Comment: please tell me from where the two activites are opened ?

Comment: ok great now tell me from where you are calling A.java and B.java ?

Comment: I agree with Nun Chai's solution: You can set a different OnClickListener on the button based on a flag value

Comment: @Amrola: from the main menu

Comment: @NunChai how do i do this?

Comment: @W.K.S I like this solution, however i would like to stick to 1 file only

Comment: @martynas: Create a flag variable (e.g. a string or an int) and pass it as an Extra to the second activity. The second activity checks the value of the flag and sets the button's onClickListener accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

call your one activity  the following :

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext() , C.class) ;
myIntent.putExtra("activity" , "A");
startActivity(myIntent); 


Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext() , C.class) ;
myIntent.putExtra("activity" , "B");
startActivity(myIntent);
```

then in C activity in you onClickListener do like the following :

```
String activity = getIntent().getExtras().getString("activity");

if(activity .equals("A") ) {


}else if (activity .equals("B")){

}
```

and give me some feedback .

Hope that Helps .

Answer (score 0):

The content of your two types of functionality should go into two functions,

```
public void functionA(){

//One functionality here

//increment/decrement your flag 

}

public void functionB(){

//Second functionality here

//increment/decrement your flag 

}
```

Then in your onCLickListener:

```
   private View.OnClickListener onPress = new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            If(flag == somevalue){
                functionA();
            }else {
                functionB();
                }

            }
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

From your calling code, add an extra to your intent to indicate which action should be taken when the button is clicked, e.g.

```
intent.putExtra("click_option", 1);
```

Then in your activity, simply check for the existance of the extra and it's value:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null & extras.containsKey("click_option")) {
    // do something
}
```